# Get an element from a list Terraform

Tags: list, terraform

I have a small question about Terraform but I can't find a solution online. Imagine the following scenario:

```
data "aws_vpc" "vpc_name" {
  id = var.vpc_id
}

data "aws_subnet_ids" "vpc_subnets" {
  vpc_id = data.aws_vpc.vpc_name.id
}
```

And imagine I create an EC2 instance like this:

```
resource "aws_instance" "ec2_test" {
  ...
  ami                  = ...
  instance_type        = ...
  subnet_id            = element(tolist(data.aws_subnet_ids.vpc_subnets.ids), 1)
  ...
```

In the subnet, I have selected an element using the element function and converted the list of subnet ids to a list.

Now, I have two questions:

1. Is it possible to select the first subnet without doing the conversion to list (tolist)? I wonder why I can do something like data.aws_subnet_ids.vpc_subnets[1] or something like that?
2. How can I retrieve a random id from the list of subnets?

Regards,

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need the tolist operation, because aws_subnet_ids.ids is a set. You could clean it up a little and say `tolist(data.aws_subnet_ids.vpc_subnets.ids)[0]`.

To get a random number, use the [random provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/random/latest/docs).

Answer (score 1):

Okay, but what if you have the following stupid thing going on:

```
output "ids" {
  value = values(tomap({
    for k, public in aws_subnet.public : k => public.id
  }))
}
```

I am trying to get any value from this list that I generated after maybe 5 hours of my life. :) I fully get it, that this might not be seen at all, but imagine you have 3 subnets for public, 3 for private, 3 for something else. You try to get the 3 public going on. The case is on random. Each time a random value from these 3 gets picked up. Reason you might ask trying to outsmart yourself.

Answer (score 0):

With v0.15: `one(my_set)` works on zero/one element list/set.

Otherwise `tolist(my_set)[0]` is v0.12 compatible.

For dirty tricks lovers with one element primitive string: `join("", my_set)`.

- https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/one